# Extjs4: How to add head title from CheckboxModel in grid?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, grid

**I want to add header title from CheckboxModel column in grid.**

Truth be told, I wanted to add multiple checkbox column in grid like that.(attached image file)
My mission is one checkbox have to select only one. But extjs does not have supported RadioModel.
So I had an idea. I could use CheckboxModel of selModel in grid.

BUT it also had a problem. I could not add title in CheckboxModel column.
1. Ankus.js

```
 {
                margin: '10 0 0 0',
                xtype: 'grid',
                minHeight: 100,
                layout: 'fit',
                frame: true,
                resizable: true,
                itemId: 'previewGrid',
                selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
                    ignoreRightMouseSelection: true,
                    headerWidth: 66,
                    dataIndex: "classIndex",
                    injectCheckbox:"last",

                }), ......
```

See the image : http://goo.gl/znbTwU

1. ext-them-gray-all.css
   I removed 'x-column-header-inner-empty' elements. BUT it did't work.
   How do I do?

Please help me.